# Performance Issue While Fecthing the Record and Displaying in Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am fetching the records from two table One is VehicleDetails and other one is Barcodedetails.

Vehicle Details Contains 10,000 records and Barcode Details Contains 1.1 million records and Each vehicle is Mapped to a specific Bardcode.

currently what I am doing is first is getting all the BarcodeDetails from BarcodeDetailsTable and its take 8 secs to complete it,

```
List<VTSBarCodeDetail> barCodeDetailMaster = barCodeDetailRepository.Get(null, null) as List<VTSBarCodeDetail>;
```

then I will get the Vehicle Details

```
List<VTSVehicleRegistrationObject> vehicleRegObject = (Some  Simple query to get the VehicleRegobject)
```

and then I am running a for loop in this for loop I am adding barcodeno passtype etc details to a list. this for loop is taking 1 min of time to complete it for 6k records.
here is my code and log file have a look at this.

```
foreach (VTSVehicleRegistrationObject item in vehicleRegObject)
{
  barCodeDetails = barCodeDetailMaster.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Convert.ToInt32(item.VehicleId) && x.BarCodeId == item.BarCodeId).FirstOrDefault();
  { 
  //some Logic add item to this list.
  }
```

Comment: Do NOT fetch all records from Barcode Details which contains 11Lakhs records. Write a single LINQ/SQL statement that select desired column and apply a JOIN on these two tables.

Comment: i think it will matter if you preprocess all this computations in sql level by using stored procedure for example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you trying to do this? A bit more context will be helpful. If you really want to BarCodeDetails for each VehicleDetail entry then yes the nested loop will take time and I mean a very long time.

The line: //some Logic add item to this list.

suggests that you want to process each entry.

Assuming that you really want to do this and process 10000 x 1.1 million entries, here are few suggestions:

- Split VehicleDetails fetch in batches of reasonable numbers (like 10 or 50) and load corresponding records from VehicleDetails...
- Use threads to process the records (beware that overuse of threading will kill the benefits)

If the output is not supposed to be in order, you can probably do more clever things with threads to process and merge the data in list but this all depends what you want to do....

Hope this helps or shout with more details if you need more help

Answer (score -1):

barCodeDetails = barCodeDetailMaster.Where(x => x.VehicleId == Convert.ToInt32(item.VehicleId) && x.BarCodeId == item.BarCodeId).FirstOrDefault();

Please change as below.

barCodeDetails = barCodeDetailMaster.FirestOrDefault(x => x.VehicleId == Convert.ToInt32(item.VehicleId) && x.BarCodeId == item.BarCodeId);